# foreach not printing the query result in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp, foreach, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

**my controller**

```
        $data= $this->Contact->find('all',array(
        'conditions' => array('Contact.User_id' => $id)));

    $this->loadModel('Calllog');
      foreach($data as $row){

      $mobile=  $row['Contact']['mobileNo'];
      $home=  $row['Contact']['homeNo'];
      $work=  $row['Contact']['workNo'];


      $recent=$this->Calllog->find('all',
          array('order'=>'Calllog.idCallLog DESC',
              'limit' => 1,
              'conditions' => array('Calllog.mobileNo' => array($mobile,$work,$home ),
                  'Calllog.User_id' => $id


              )));

    debug($recent);
      $this->set('recent',$recent);


    }
```

in my view i have this line

```
  <?php  foreach($recent as $as): ?> <?php echo $as['Calllog']['mobileNo'];?>
```

but isn't displaying anything even not  any error

i debug the result in which i am getting one row means   working fine 
and i have also dump sql query in which query is running fine and when i run this query in         phpmyadmin it is giving me the one row which is what i want .. but why  it is  not echoing the result on  my view page

**debug result**

```
      array(
      (int) 0 => array(
       'CallLog' => array(
       'idCallLog =>'3',
        'mobileNo'=>'12345'
         'User_id'=>'1'
          )))
```

**and then after 4 lines**

```
         array()
```

Comment: Can you add here the debug result of `$recent` (but execute it from the view)?

Comment: i didnt get your question but i am posting my debug result

Comment: @Nunser i have edited my question... please check the debug result

Comment: Looking at the debug, shouldn't it be `$as['CallLog']['mobileNo']` (capital third L) in the echo?

Comment: @Nunser okk i i get it that what i am doing wrong ... i am not getting the result in query ... actually when i dump the queries .. what i see is there are three queries which i am viewing in my view page ... the first query has given me the one row .. but the seconnd is running twice ..in which 2nd time it is giving me one row and in third it is not giving me any result ... want i want is i want to run both the queries only 1 time ..

Comment: why the Calllog query running twice.. because i think loop has to be stop when second query has given the one row according to the condition..why it is keep looping all the way

Comment: you are setting $recent in a loop. $recent is over-writing on each iteration, It does not have any result of last record of loop.

Comment: @MoyedAnsari then what should i do ??? do i have to set $recent outside of the loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data= $this->Contact->find('all',array(
        'conditions' => array('Contact.User_id' => $id)));

$recent = array();

$this->loadModel('Calllog');
foreach($data as $row){

  $mobile=  $row['Contact']['mobileNo'];
  $home=  $row['Contact']['homeNo'];
  $work=  $row['Contact']['workNo'];


  $recent[]=$this->Calllog->find('all',
          array('order'=>'Calllog.idCallLog DESC',
              'limit' => 1,
              'conditions' => array('Calllog.mobileNo' => array($mobile,$work,$home ),
                  'Calllog.User_id' => $id
          )));

}

$this->set('recent',$recent);
debug($recent);
```